# DateTime Stamp as Filename - Progress4gl

Tags: progress-4gl

In Progress 4gl,how to use DateTime Stamp as a Filename , such  that each time I run a program it should create a new output csv file? Im using Progress version 11.5..For eg.,  outfilename = "c:\progress\?.csv". Instead of '?' , what should I replace to get a DateTime Stamp as a filename.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do what you're looking for:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISO-DATE(now), ":", "-"), ".", "-") + ".csv"):
   /* output data */
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE("c:\progress\filename_" + STRING(TODAY,"99999999") + STRING(TIME) + ".csv").
```